# Why JavaScrips works only after loading page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react app and trying initialize materialize js by jQuery.

index.html

```html
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tabs").tabs();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

**Problem:** So react renders "UserProfile" component which has materialize "tabs" in it. If I go to UserProfile route then javaScript works, but If I go to another page and return back to UserProfile, then javaScript does'not work.  Or if I will start from another page and go to UserProfile, result the same, tabs are not working.

I checked html "Elements" and it has those scripts there, they didn't disappear(And they should actually, but just in case).

**P.S.** I am new at React so maybe this code is fundamentally wrong, and I understand adding scripts below main html like that is not a good idea, but even so, I thought it should work at least. Or do I need somehow to add my scripts in components? Any help would be helpful.

Comment: `$(document).ready` only triggers on DOM ready i.e. once if you're working with a SPA.

Comment: Instead of using plain `materialize` I'd suggest to use `react materialize` using this you don't need to worry about `jquery` and any initialization- http://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/?path=/story/javascript-tabs--default

Comment: If the react app that you are building is, doing client-side navigation, the `$(document).ready` will be fired, only once when the doc is ready after rendering is done, if its possible please move the `< script/>` inside the `UserProfile` component's `componentDidMount` or use `hashchange` event of window to initialise the tabs

Comment: @ravibagul91 Did not know about `react-materialize` seems that will help, thank you.

Comment: if you don't want to use `react-materialize`, then, do the jquery tab init inside the `ComponentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Comment: @ubuntugod Could you please write an example?

Comment: @ubuntugod I tried yesterday componentDidMount(){$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".tabs").tabs();
    });} but I am getting error tabs() is not a funcion, and before that I had to install jquery. So I decided to just use below html

Comment: `tab is not a function` , is there any other `var` with the `tab` namespace in `componentDidMount` ? @airush, is `$.fn.tabs` available in `window` ?

Comment: @nivendha I wrote full code in the previous comment

Comment: @nivendha $.fn.tabs available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spend hours to that.

Everything I needed. To add this componentDidMount() in UserComponent(I know everyone said about that, but no one said about `window` before, maybe it's actually to obvious, but not for me)

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.$(".tabs").tabs(); 

/* Or initilize with Materialize */
// var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs");
// window.M.Tabs.init(elems, {});
}
```

*Without `window` you will get first error `$ undefined`, then if you add jQuery into your modules you will get "tabs() is not a function`.*

So that works fine, and you don't have to import anything.

Comment: so u didn't import `$` from jquery package previously?

Comment: Remember you don't need the ready function inside the componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has nothing to do with React, `$(document).ready` will ensure the callback executes after the html document is fully loaded, but there's no guarantee it will wait for `react.render` to finish executing, which means your callback is running before React adds the component to the DOM and isn't finding any `.tabs`.

Maybe you're looking to do whatever you want to do using `componentDidMount()`? React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to type the complete example as I am on phone now. But, here is the idea if you don't want to use `react-materialize`.

Create a Tab component. To do this:

`import M from "<path to materialize js or from materialize npm package if installed>"`

Inside, `componentDidMount` init the tab using pure JS instead of jQuery like `M.Tabs.init(this.Tab)`

Then in `render` method, add `ref` attribute to `ul` element like `ref={Tab => this.Tab = Tab }`.

Export the component and use like `<Tab />`

Hope this helps.

If you are going with jQuery(after doing `npm i jquery --save` and importing it) for any other reason, then don't do document ready, as in react, the `componentDidMount` is enough to handle init of jQuery code as it is called after the page is rendered.